# How do you get Flask to detect changes in static files?

Tags: python, flask

I need Flask to detect changes made in files in the static folder, say .css, .js, .jpg files. I have disabled caching for certain views but I would like to know if there is a way to do it with Flask.

Comment: What are you wanting Flask to do when it detects these files have changed?

Comment: render the new version inside the template. for example images .

Comment: But that has nothing to do with Flask; it's your browser that renders these.

Comment: sure, maybe I didn't ask the right question. I just want to render the newest versions of charts I am putting in the static directory each time they change.

Comment: may be are you looking for something  like webassets or flask-assets :  http://flask-assets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ ?

Comment: That will do it. thanks.

Comment: you're welcome but webassets is mainly oriented to manage css and js assets. For images and any kind of binary content, it's more difficult: https://github.com/miracle2k/webassets/issues/117 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use webassets or [flask-assets](http://flask-assets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)  to manage your static contents but it's better suited for managing js or css contents

Answer (score -2):

try using following API scenerio

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
```